# rails, selecting a radio button to a submit form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, radio-button, twitter-bootstrap

i was wondering if there was a way to submit a form when a radio button is pressed, without needing the 'submit' button.

i have the code...

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle-name="filter" data-toggle="buttons-radio" >
   <button value="0" class="btn" data-toggle="button">Newest</button>
   <button value="1" class="btn" data-toggle="button">Score</button>
</div>
```

im using twitters bootstrap btw. i was wondering if it was possible to get into my lessons#index action from clicking either of those 2 buttons? i wanted the user to be able to filter by newest/score and was going to pass one of those values into my index action.

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
javascript:document.formName.submit();
```

you can use this line in the onclick to submit the form without using submit button